# Нужна ли запятая перед несогласованным определением?

Tags: пунктуация

Особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса, наверное, прежде всего, определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую (,) с ее законами и стандартами.

Comment: По-моему, "прежде всего" в Вашем предложении -- не вводное. Попробуйте прочитать предложение без этого "вводного"… Автор что, не уверен в том, что "особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую"?

Я бы сделал так:
Особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса прежде всего, наверное, определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение лучше обособить. Во-первых, пропущено существительное, во-вторых, определению лучше придать поясняющий характер.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Н/о синтаксически не связано с существительном и здесь выступает в качестве уточнения. Запятая нужна. Подробно о знаках препинания при н/о - здесь:[Д.Э. Розенталь.Справочник по русскому языку: Орфография. Пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110) [Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)